# JToken is not a reference of JObject?

Tags: json.net, linqpad

I have not yet noticed that James Newton King wrote or spoke about what `JToken` *[is](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jtoken.htm)*. I have made the incorrect assumption that it somehow holds a reference to `JObject`. This is not the case as the these LINQPad statements demonstrate:

```
var json = @"
{
    ""item"": {
        ""foo"": ""4"",
        ""bar"": ""42""
    }
}
";

var jO = JObject.Parse(json);
var jToken = jO["item"]["foo"];

jToken = "5";

jO.ToString().Dump("jO");

jToken.Dump("jToken");
```

The output:

```
jO
{
  "item": {
    "foo": "4",
    "bar": "42"
  }
}

jToken
5
```

Should not `jO["item"]["foo"] == 5`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, let's talk about what a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) is.

- `JToken` is the abstract base class for `JObject`, `JArray`, `JProperty` and `JValue`.
- `JObject` is a collection of `JProperty` objects.  A `JObject` cannot hold any other kind of `JToken`.
- `JProperty` is a name-value pair.  The name is always a string, and the value can be any kind of `JToken` except another `JProperty`.
- `JArray` is an array of `JToken` objects of any kind except `JProperty`.
- `JValue` represents a JSON primitive value.  It can contain a string, number, boolean, date or null.  Note that `JValue` is a reference type like all other JTokens.

The above classes are intended to model the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/).

Now let's talk about what you're doing and where you're getting confused.

In your code, you are first creating a JObject.  The JObject contains one JProperty called `item`.  The value of `item` is another JObject which contains two JProperties, called `foo` and `bar`.  The values of these JProperties are both JValues containing strings (`4` and `42`, respectively).

Next, you use the JToken indexer syntax to get a reference to the *value* of the `foo` JProperty (a JValue which contains the string value `4`) and assign that reference to your `jToken` variable.  Note the declared type of this variable is JToken, even though the actual type of the value here is in fact JValue.  (You can see this if you do `jToken.GetType().Name.Dump("jToken type")` )

With me so far?

OK, here is where I think you are getting confused.  JToken provides implicit and explicit conversions which allow it to be assigned from or cast to various .NET primitives.  If you do `jToken = "5"` that really means the same thing as `jToken = new JValue("5")`.  So what you have done is to replace the reference that your `jToken` variable had (to the JValue containing `4`) with a new reference to a different JValue containing `5`.  This obviously will have no effect on the original JObject.

If you are trying to modify the value of the original JValue, you need to cast your `jToken` to JValue and then use the `Value` setter to set it.

```
((JValue)jToken).Value = "5";
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/StIGxM

Comment: James Newton King should use this documentation :)

Comment: @rasx: Why? How is this case any different than assigning a value from a property to a local variable and changing that variable expecting the original property to be changed. You're reassigning the value of that variable, you're not modifying the object it refers to...

Answer (score 1):

Actually `JToken` has a reference to its parent (check `Parent` property).
Back to your example - in this line `jToken = "5";` you are creating new `JToken` (to be more specific, string is implicitly converted to `JValue`). Basically it is the same as `jToken = new JValue("5");` So variable `jToken` is now pointing to brand new `JValue`.  This explains why the change is not reflected in original `JObject`.
To fix your example use: `((JValue)jToken).Value = "5";`