# JSON.NET: Obtain JObject from JProperty Value

Tags: json.net

I'm stuck on something:

I deserialized a JSON file using JObject.Load:

```
// get the JSON into an object 
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(new
  JsonTextReader(new StreamReader("mydoc.json")));
```

Fine. I now have a populate jsonObject.

Now I iterate through its properties like this:

```
foreach (JProperty jsonRootProperty in jsonObject.Properties())
  {    
    if (jsonRootProperty.Name=="Hotel")
    {
      ... !!! I just want a JObject here...
    }
  }
```

Once I find a property with a Name equal to "Hotel", I want that property's value as a JObject. The catch is that the Hotel property name might be a single value (say, a string), or it might be a JSON object or a JSON array.

How can I get the property's value into a JObject variable so that I can pass it to another function that accepts a JObject parameter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get the `Value` of the `JProperty`, which is a `JToken`, and look at its `Type`.  This property will tell you if the token is an Object, Array, String, etc.  If the token type is Object, then you can simply cast it to a `JObject` and pass it to your function.  If the token type is something other than Object and your function has to have a `JObject`, then you'll need to wrap the value in a `JObject` in order to make it work.

```
foreach (JProperty jsonRootProperty in jsonObject.Properties())
{    
    if (jsonRootProperty.Name=="Hotel")
    {
        JToken value = jsonRootProperty.Value;
        if (value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            FunctionThatAcceptsJObject((JObject)value);
        }
        else
        {
            FunctionThatAcceptsJObject(new JObject(new JProperty("value", value)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Off subject but I am a great admirer of you, your knowledge of JSON.NET, and willingness to share it--thank you for replying). Looks good but can you please explain more about "wrap the value in a JObject"? I wasted many hours struggling with how to get a JToken into a JObject and clearly I'm missing something about how JTokens and JObjects relate to each other...

Comment: The first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38005957/10263) might help you then.  It talks about how JToken, JObject, etc. relate.  Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: Awesome! That link looks like a treasure-trove of additional information. That, along your answer here, should set me on the right path to jump these final JSON.NET hurdles!