# JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?

Tags: json.net

As a follow up to my question here:
[JSON.NET: Obtain JObject from JProperty Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207050/json-net-obtain-jobject-from-jproperty-value) ...

I read links and digested the above comments and advice. Now I wonder: Is there a good reason why there is no "direct" (i.e., easy) way to turn the Value of a JProperty object into a JObject? It seems like a lot of work to get to a JToken and then have to construct if statements, etc. This isn't to complain about the extra work; rather, it's to admit that I still think I don't understand the true purpose of JToken. At one time, all FedEx packages first routed to Memphis: It seems that all objects can/should go to JToken first then be parceled to the actual target object type. Is that a way to think about it?

In other words, is there ever a good reason to use JToken--or is it just that so many other functions return a JToken and then you have to just deal with that? The JSON.NET manual gives ways to cast JToken to other types (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Operators_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) but doesn't mention going from JToken to JObject...

I find that JObject is usually what I want to have in order to work with JSON and to map from JSON to my .NET classes and back again--as well as doing a host of other operations. I still wonder what is the compelling reason to ever use a JToken object?

Comment: `JToken` represents any possible token in a JSON file.  If you have some JSON and don't know in advance what might be inside, you can parse it with `JToken.Parse()` and get a result as long as the JSON is valid.  `JObject.Parse()`, `JArray.Parse()` and `JValue.Parse()` will throw if the root JSON token is not of the expected type.

Comment: To round-out your otherwise excellent summary, what exactly is a JSON token (I for one am still new to JSON)?

Comment: From the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) (which is really quite simple), it would be an object, array, value, string or number.

Comment: Please somehow move your comment to answer so I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

From the [standard](http://www.json.org/), JSON is built out of the following five types of token:

- *object*: an unordered set of name/value pairs.
- *array*: an ordered collection of values.
- *value*: a *string* in double quotes, or a *number*, or `true` or `false` or `null`, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.
- *string*
- *number*.

[`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) is an abstract base class that represents any one of these possible tokens. If you have some JSON and don't know in advance what might be inside, you can parse it with [`JToken.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm) and get a result as long as the JSON is well-formed. [`JObject.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) and [`JArray.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) will throw if the root JSON token is not of the expected type.  And there is no [`JValue.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) to parse a JSON string you know to represent an "atomic" value, requiring the use of `JToken.Parse()` in such a case.

Similarly, [`JToken.FromObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) may be used to serialize any sort of c# object to a `JToken` hierarchy without needing to know in advance the resulting JSON type.  This can be useful e.g. when writing generic serialization-related code.

Comment: I don't see the definition of token in the JSON standard you referenced. If a value is a superset of a token (token or true or false or null), why should we care about tokens when parsing JSON?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - Seems there's an inconsistency in terminology between Newtonsoft and https://json.org/.  https://json.org/ uses "value" to mean JSON of any type.  Newtonsoft uses `JValue` for a primitive value (true/false/null/string/number), and "token" for JSON of any type.