# Json.Net JArray creation and retrieving in a generic way?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

If I have a json object like this:

```
{
    "name": "value"
}
```

I can do `jobjectCurrent["name"]` and get the reference to that object.

However, if I have a json like this:

```
{
    "items":[]
}
```

I can NOT do `jobjectCurrent["items"]`. How would I find out then if items exists and if its a jarray and get a reference to the jarray so I can add items?

Is there a syntax where I can generically access normal key/value pairs as well as arrays?

Comment: `jobjectCurrent["items"]` works just fine, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/sG2lCr.  Could you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: @dbc -- hmm... I just tried it again and it seems like its working now lol... might have been user error before... I'll keep down this path and see if it works, if not, I'll respond again. Thx.

Comment: @dbc Ok... I see whats going on... json.net is structured in a way where they have different hierarchy of objects... I.e. jArray and jObject are not compatible types, so the code gets kind of hokey. Would have been nice to have a root object that can be any type of json object.

Comment: *Would have been nice to have a root object that can be any type of json object.* -- there is such an object.  Use [`JToken.Parse()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm).  See [JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212978/3744182).

Comment: @dbc, oh cool. Right now my public method takes a JObject. Is there any advantage to keeping it a JObject? vs switching everything to a JToken? I dunno... a JObject seems more like the type that should go into public methods. I guess I can get the first token and switch to JTokens internally.

Comment: If your method requires that the incoming JSON be an unordered collection of key/value pairs, then use a `JObject`.  If the incoming JSON is completely unconstrained, use `JToken`.