# Adding JArray to an existing property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "ID":123,
  "Products":null,
  "Title":"Products"
}
```

I want to add some data from DB to the "Products" node so my final json will look like so:

```
{
  "ID":123,
  "Products":[
      {
        "ID":1,
        "Name":"AA"
      },
      {
        "ID":2,
        "Name":"BB"
      }
    ],
  "Title":"Products"
}
```

I'm using this code:

```
internal class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//simulate DB
var products= new List<Product>()
{
    new Product() {ID=1,Name="AA" },
    new Product() {ID=2,Name="BB" }
};

string JSONstr = FilesUtils.OpenFile(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Sample.json"));
JObject JSON = JObject.Parse(JSONstr);
        ((JValue)JSON["Products"]).Value = JObject.FromObject(products);
```

But I get an exception:

> Object serialized to Array. JObject instance expected.

Comment: `JSON["Products"] = JToken.FromObject(products);` should work.

Comment: you the king ! - BTW how can i add new property to the root then?

Comment: The same way - just do `JSON["NewName"] = JToken.FromObject(newValue);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
JSON["Products"] = JToken.FromObject(products);
```

To add a new property, do the same thing, e.g.:

```
JSON["TimeStamp"] = JToken.FromObject(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Notes:

- The [item setter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) for `JObject` will add or replace the property with the specified name `"Products"`.
- [`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) serializes any .Net object to a [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) hierarchy.  [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) is the abstract base class of this hierarchy and so can represent both arrays, objects, and primitives.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212978/3744182) for details.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1YVv3d).

Answer (score 0):

The expected object will have to be (according to your JSON). If that's the JSON you want you might consider wrapping it up and adding the ID and a Title as shown in the JSON.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class YourObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```