# Deserialize selected JSON object from JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string that looks similar to this:

```
{
    "automatic" : "true",
    "brainstorm" : "1000",
    "zombies" : [{ "Name" : "Fred", "Grrh" : "50" }, { "Name" : "Sally", "Grrh" : "67" }, { "Name" : "Chris", "Grrh" : "23" }],
    "nightSkyRadius" : "30"
    ... could be anything here or at the same level as zombies ...
}
```

So, in my scenario I know the Zombie objects in the array will always be the same. But I don't know anything else beyond that. That is to say, there could be any number of values at the same root as the `zombies` value.

So my question is, how do I using Json.NET deserialize only my `zombies`? I don't know what the other values are (if values is the right term) so I cannot just create an object that describes the incoming Json string. So I'm thinking I can just pick `zombies` out of the json string and deserialize it then.

But, I thought, I'd have to write a string parser that would pull `zombies` out.. that seems like an extra unnecessary step. Can't `Json.NET` do this for me?

Also, I've tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);` but that can only handle the case when one zombie is specified in the response string.

Thanks, I hope `zombies` made this problem seem cooler lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Zombie class and parse the json into that. Newtonsoft is smart enough to decode it for you

```
public class zombies
{
    public string Name;
    public int Grrh;
}
```

Now you can do

```
var zombies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<zombies>>(responseString);
```

Comment: My current code base asks for the list to be in `JToken`s do you know how I might get the list that way? `JToken` that represents the `zombies` object.

Comment: Personally I don't think you are doing yourself a favor using JTokens for this as its really only used when you aren't sure whats going to be inside it. Since you only want the zombie object deserializing it into a defined object is going to make working with it much easier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211719/json-net-why-use-jtoken-ever

Comment: Right, but in my situation I can't exactly change the implementation. Good point though. EDIT: I'm working with a sql interface that takes `JToken`

Answer (score 1):

If you need only array of zombies you can simple deserialize object with only one auto property array of zombies

```
public class Zombie {
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Grrh {get;set;}
}

public class Zombies {
public IEnumerable<Zombie> ZombieCollection {get;set;}
}
```

Then

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Zombies>(responseString)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass that entire Json Object in to an object with just a list of Zombies as a collection on it. Specifying the `JsonPropertyAttribute` it will then deserialize the zombies property only, and ignore everything else it cant map to a thing on your object.

assuming a zombie class of:

```
public class Zombie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Grrh {get; set; }
}
```

and a class to hold the entire json object (which will just be the zombie collection)

```
public class MyZombieJsonData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "zombies")]
    public List<Zombie> ZombieList { get; set; }
}
```

then wherever you have access to the json string, you can do:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyZombieJsonData>(theJsonDataAsAString);
```

where `theJsonDataAsAString` is your entire Json data, including the stuff you dont know about and dont want to deserialize, as a string type.

Comment: nice use of `JsonProperty`