# Convert JToken To JObject

Tags: c#, json, oauth, .net-core

I'm trying to create an OAuth Handler in .Net Core, The api I'm using wraps the user data response in an property called data, But the OAuthTicket Context Expects a JObject and Not A JToken

```
var payload = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())["data"];        
var context = new OAuthCreatingTicketContext(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                    properties, Context, Scheme, Options, Backchannel, tokens, payload);

context.RunClaimActions();
```

How can I Convert a JToken To JObject?

Comment: `JObject` is a subclass of `JToken`, so if `payload` is in fact a `JObject`, you can just cast it.  See [JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38211719/3744182).  But we need to see the JSON to be sure that will work.

Comment: @dbc Isn't the inheritance chain go as the following? JObject -> JContainer -> JToken.  It's a bit wierd to me casting a base  class to its super

Comment: Hmm, It seems JContainer and JToken are abstract. Thanks

Comment: Close as a duplicate of [JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38211719/3744182) then, or add an answer?

Comment: @dbc that link answers the question pretty much, the questions a bit different but I don’t want the split the votes let’s close as duplicate, so if anyone gets here it will link to your answer there

Comment: OK, done.  Glad to help.

Comment: try this `JObject object = token.ToObject<JObject>();`