# Serializing plain values and objects with JObject.FromObject

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have problem with serializing objects using Newtonsoft.JSON. I have a method which creates EventGridEvent object:

```
public EventGridEvent CreateEvent(object data) => 
    new EventGridEvent
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        EventTime = DateTime.Now,
        Data = JObject.FromObject(data, JsonSerializer),
        ...other properties
    }
```

When the method is called with "proper" object, everything serializes properly. The problem is if the data is a plain value i.e. integer or string. In this case I get an exception *Object serialized to Integer. JObject instance expected*. How to detect if object can be serialized with `JObject.FromObject` and if not use its plain value (without using try/catch)?

Comment: Why not just do `JToken.FromObject()` and modify `Data` to be of type `JToken`?  a `JToken` can represent any sort of JSON value, not just an object.  See: [JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38211719/3744182).

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I need. Thank you so much - if you wish, please copy it to the answer, so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `EventGridEvent.Data` can hold any type of JSON value, you should modify it to be of type [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) and use [`JToken.FromObject(Object, JsonSerializer)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject_1.htm), i.e.:

```
public class EventGridEvent 
{
    public JToken Data { get; set; }
    // ...other properties
}
```

And then do

```
Data = JToken.FromObject(data, JsonSerializer),
```

A [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm)

> Represents an abstract JSON token.

It can be used to hold the JSON representation of any JSON type including an  array, object, or primitive value.  See: *[JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38211719/3744182)*.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to serialize a nullable value like an int? or string, JToken.FromObject() will throw an error. I've found that the implicit operator (called by casting) works better.

```
string s = null;
int? i = null;
JObject obj = new JObject();

// obj.Add(JToken.FromObject(s)); // throws exception
// obj.Add(JToken.FromObject(i)); // throws exception

obj.Add((JToken)s); // works
obj.Add((JToken)i); // works
```