# JSON output is not indented when using Formatting.Indented with SerializeObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to generate an indented JSON output using JSON.Net. The first code does not work

```
var data = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
```

However, this second code does work

```
var data = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
var json = JValue.Parse(data).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

I'm a bit confused why both versions don't give the same output.

Comment: In the first example you are **double-serializing** a JSON string.  I.e. a string that is already JSON is being serialized as a JSON string literal.  Json.NET will not reformat or otherwise modify a string literal during serialization.  In the second case, you need to be aware that [there is no static method `JValue.Parse()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212978/3744182), so you are actually calling the `JToken.Parse()` method on the base class.  Thus you deserialize the JSON into a `JToken`, then re-serialize it to JSON, which will cause it to get reformatted.

Comment: In the first example why are you calling SerializeObject? What is the point?

Comment: Thanks, dbc. _"Json.NET will not reformat or otherwise modify a string literal during serialization"_ answered my question.