# How to Convert Object to Jtoken in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

```
public void Set(string name, object content)
        {
   
         
            this.Json.Add(name, content);
            
        }
```

How can I convert  content variable to Jtoken so that I can perform Json.add operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`JObject.FromObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject.htm):

```
this.Json.Add(name, JObject.FromObject(content));
```

Or `JValue.FromObject` if you are expecting values which are not mapped to json objects:

```
this.Json.Add(name, JValue.FromObject(content));
```

Comment: @UbaidUllah cause boolean is not mapped to json object. You can use `JValue.FromObject(content)` if not only classes are expected.

Comment: Solved , Thankyou

Comment: @UbaidUllah was glad to help.

Comment: FYI, there is no [`JValue.FromObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm), you're actually calling the static method on the base class `JToken`.  See: [JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212978/3744182).